# How to Write to a User.Config file through ConfigurationManager?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files, configurationmanager, settings

I'm trying to persist user settings to a configuration file using ConfigurationManager.

I want to scope these settings to the user only, because application changes can't be saved on Vista/Win 7 without admin privileges.

This seems to get me the user's configuration, which appears to be saved here in Win 7 ([Drive]:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\[ApplicationName]\[AssemblyName][hash]\[Version\)

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
```

Whenever I try to save any changes at all to this config I get this exception:

```
InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
Message="ConfigurationSection properties cannot be edited when locked."
Source="System.Configuration"
StackTrace:
    at System.Configuration.SectionInformation.VerifyIsEditable()
    at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.GetConfigDefinitionUpdates(Boolean requireUpdates, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceSaveAll, ConfigDefinitionUpdates& definitionUpdates, ArrayList& configSourceUpdates)
```

I have tried adding a custom ConfigurationSection to this config. I have tried adding to the AppSettingsSection. Whenever I call `config.Save()` it throws the exception above.

Any ideas?

I tried using the ApplicationSettingsBase class through the Project->Settings designer, but it doesn't appear that you can save custom types with this. I want similar functionality with the ability to save custom types.

Comment: Turns out you CAN use custom to types with the Project->Settings designer. They don't list them in the type dialog, but if you type in the right name/namespace you can use any type you want. The type should be XmlSerializable or convertable to/from string with a TypeConverter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the SectionInformation.AllowExeDefinition value for the section:

```
 Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming);
UserSettings settings;
if ((settings = (UserSettings)configuration.Sections[GENERAL_USER_SETTINGS]) == null)
{
      settings = new UserSettings();
      settings.SectionInformation.AllowExeDefinition =   
                 ConfigurationAllowExeDefinition.MachineToLocalUser;
      configuration.Sections.Add(GENERAL_USER_SETTINGS, settings);
      configuration.Save();
}
```

The default value is ConfigurationAllowExeDefinition.MachineToApplication which allows only to place the section on machine.config and app.exe.config.

Comment: I'll try that. I tried setting the AllowExeDefinition property once and caused the same exception that config.Save() fired off. I'll copy this code segment and try again.

Comment: It appears I needed to set the AllowExeDefinition BEFORE adding the section and saving the changes for the first time. Now everything appears to be working fine.

Comment: for some reason, using the _ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration_ with _ConfigurationUserLevel_ overload, didn't allowed me to edit & save the file by claiming that _ConfigurationSection properties cannot be edited when locked_. only when I've used the _string exepath_ overload, I was capable of saving the configuration.

Comment: I just encountered this.   I fixed it by updating the new section before adding it to the config.Sections collection.

Comment: where is UserSettings ? in framework 4.8?